# Permissioning in Hyperlededger Fabric Composer transactions

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have two `Participants` A and B, each have their own `identity` issued to them by the `CA`

There is a transaction that enables one `Participant` to transfer `Coins` to the other.

```
participant Person identified by id {
    o String id
    o String firstName
    o String lastName
    o Double coins
}
```

The transaction cto file

```
transaction TransferCoins {
    o Double coinsTransferred      
    --> Person receiver
    --> Person sender
}
```

The `permissions.acl` file

```
rule PersonCanModifyOnlySelf {
    description: "Allow Persons to modify only their profile"
    participant(p): "org.varun.business.Person"
    operation: READ, UPDATE, DELETE
    resource(r): "org.varun.business.Person"
    condition: (r.getIdentifier() === p.getIdentifier())
    action: ALLOW
}

rule PersonCanReadAllProfile {
    description: "Allow Persons read access to other Persons"
    participant: "org.varun.business.Person"
    operation: READ
    resource: "org.varun.business.Person"
    action: ALLOW
}
```

The transaction.js file

```
/**
 * Person to Person transaction
 * @param {org.varun.business.TransferCoins} transferCoins
 * @transaction
 */
function TransferCoins(transferCoins) {

    var coinsToTransfer = transferCoins.coinsTransferred;
    transferCoins.sender.coins = transferCoins.sender.coins - coinsToTransfer;
    transferCoins.receiver.coins = transferCoins.receiver.coins + coinsToTransfer;

    return getParticipantRegistry('org.varun.business.Person')
        .then(registry => {
            return registry.updateAll([transferCoins.sender, transferCoins.receiver]);
        })                
}
```

In short

- Each Person can only `update` their own profile
- Each Person has universal `read` access

When the `TransferCoins` function is called, coins are subtracted from A while coins are added to B. The participant registry is called and updated.

Now If A were to call this transaction, I am getting an error saying A cannot update B's coins (Obviously due to acl defined above). So how does this kind of transaction work? Could someone please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

good question!

So I would have two transactions defined:

InitiateTransfer {}
AcceptTransfer{}

in your model.

InitiateTransfer (transaction function) will be invoked by Participant A. Upon invoking, you can emit an event following update, such as a Node Red event - to email Participant B of an Incoming Transfer, with a link in the email etc to go and accept the transfer.

Participant B signs into the application and accepts the transfer (ultimately invoking AcceptTransfer() transaction function).

Participant A and Participant B are two separate transactions, and won't contravene your existing ACL conditions. Whether or not you want the CoinTransfer to update a balance on a Participant or an Asset, (eg account-style with a relationship to Participant, in the transaction - see `***NOTE` below) is entirely up to you.

Transaction processor functions will wait for Promises to be resolved, before committing the transaction. If a promise is rejected, the transaction will fail.

Changes made by Composer transactions are atomic, either the transaction (as you've defined it) is successful and all changes are applied, or the transaction fails and no changes are applied per that transaction. Suggest to also see 'Error Handling' in the docs specifically relating to handling errors if a transaction does not get 'committed' by the Fabric or blockchain itself (so therefore, whether Participant B would have a transaction to work with) -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/js_scripts.html

*****NOTE:***
You may (up to you) wish to consider what model is set up. You raise the concept of maintaining a balance (initiator and acceptor) after transfer - this might be modeled as an Asset (eg. coinAccount), with an ID field, coinBalance, and coinHolder (link to Person) minimally.   The transaction is initiated by the initiator and updates its account (reducing coinAccount balance) and similarly, a separate transaction updates the acceptor coinAccount balance.

Comment: Well the issue here is, only a `Participant` that is the `coinHolder` should have `update` access to it, which brings me back to the same problem. Because you don't want `A` to have `update` access to `B` assets.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Have given you an upvote, but the thing is, if B rejects the request transaction of A, then the changes to A will need to roll back. The atomic nature of transactions is restricted to one transaction itself and not a request-accept pair as what you have suggested here. Any thoughts?

Comment: right. So then you need to have an accept notification back to Participant A, before A can initiate the transfer in the blockchain. The initial 'request' and 'accept/reject' notifications can either be 'inside' the blockchain or outside it (that's up to you if it needs recording on the blockchain). If B accepts, A gets notified and completes the transfer.

Comment: Nevermind, I read the docs very carefully there is another `Transaction` option in the `.acl` file. No example is given anywhere and barely 2-3 lines were written on this. I am currently testing it out, will post the answer if my unit tests clear. Basically you can let A and B have `update` access to each other's `assets` but allow the change to only happen via a transaction, so you control what change happens automatically

Comment: try something like:

Answer (score 0):

I see, at asset level as well. A transaction is submitted with one identity. In your case, participant A's. If ACLs restrict him/her to its own record, then that regime makes it hard for a transaction processor to achieve what you want in a single blockchain transaction.

So is it possible to submit the transaction with a party, that is not tied to A or B but can update both? That might be the best way. The transaction history would be used to see what changes occurred once the transaction is committed.

A listing record pairing sender and receiver and timestamp etc, could also be recorded as part of the same transaction logic if need be (for the purposes of reporting or otherwise).

Comment: I was thinking of that, but then one of the points of blockchain is to know who submitted the transaction. In this case a generic party may cater to multiple people, it is important to know whether A or B initiated the transaction.

Comment: I agree. The problem is around transaction submitter ('A')  not being able to update party B's record due to ACLs. I also assume you want the transfer to occur as one transaction or unit of work.

Comment: I don't mind it being 2 or even 3 transfers. Ideally, A should initiate the transaction, B accepts it, and then it happens.